# Rails: Linking directly to a JavaScript file in production

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, production-environment

I have a JavaScript file in my Rails project that I'd like to be able to link to directly.

When running in development mode, I can just link to "/assets/myFile.js" and it works fine. However, in production mode, that doesn't appear to be the case.

I really don't know enough about the Asset Pipeline, etc. to figure out what's going on here.

How can I link directly to this file once I've deployed my project to production?

Comment: If you're aware that your knowledge is lacking, shouldn't you try and read up first: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

Answer (score 1):

You should probably learn about the asset pipeline, but if you just want to get this working, put it in /public, e.g. /public/javascripts, and you'll be able to link to it as expected.

Comment: I went through and read up on the asset pipeline, actually. Managed to get this working by adding the file I wanted to config.assets.precompile